# How can I hide the value on the R studio or do not show the value but it can be used?

Tags: r, database, passwords

For example:

Script_1.R:

`AC <- 'tester'
Password <- '123456'`

Script_2.R:

`source('Script_1.R')
dbConnect(user = AC, password = password)`

I wanna hide the value shown on R studio but it can be used when I need to connect DB. 
Moreover, I wanna make Password '123456' to be shown ****** but the value is equal to 123456.

what should I do? Thank you

Comment: https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/managing-credentials/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using RStudio, you can use `rstudioapi::askForPassword()`, which launches a popup for you to type your password in.

If you put this straight into your code, the text you type in will not be saved to your environment:

`dbConnect(user = AC, password = rstudioapi::askForPassword())`